# java - can I skip static analysis in SonarQube?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Our project is currently using SonarQube for code coverage analysis only. Is it possible to skip/disable the static analysis part?

Answer (score 4):

No. Static analysis is the point of SonarQube.

Comment: Yeah, just for code coverage simply use the code coverage report generated by a tool ;) However you can disable all the quality rules :D